# SQL syntax help, conditional AND

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Been coding for 48 hours straight and am banging my head against the wall here. Please help me with this small issue.

My SQL query is this:

```
SELECT u.Firstname, u.Lastname, u.Rep, u.Email, u.Password, u.Gender, u.Level,
       u.Birthday, u.Achievements, u.Height, u.Unit, u.cityid, u.countryid,
       r.RegDate, ci.Name AS City, co.Name AS Country
FROM Users u, Registry r, Cities ci, Countries co
WHERE u.id = 1 AND r.uid = u.id AND u.cityid = ci.id AND u.countryid = co.id
LIMIT 1
```

My problem is that I just noticed that sometimes `Users.cityid` and `Users.countryid` are  `NULL` (which is OK).

I want the query to give me all the other info (like, return `NULL` for `City` and `Country`) for this user even if **one or both** those fields are `NULL`. How to make the `AND`-parts conditional?

I hope I'm making myself clear in my fogginess.

Comment: "Been coding for 48 hours straight " - there's your problem! ;)

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact syntax for MySql, but it sounds like you need to do outer joins on the tables that may have null results.

Comment: See ["How to keep being productive when you are tired?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1364056/27535) and don't be so silly

Comment: Haha @Mitch, gbn I think you guys are on to the root of the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `LEFT JOIN` on your tables instead of using a `WHERE`.

So your FROM turns into:

```
FROM Users u JOIN Registry r on u.id = r.uid 
LEFT JOIN Cities ci ON u.cityid = ci.id
LEFT JOIN Countries co ON u.countryid = co.id
WHERE u.id = 1 LIMIT 1
```

The `LEFT JOIN` is an `OUTER` join; it will join across the tables where the leftmost (hence the `LEFT` in the `JOIN`) term in the `JOIN` (i.e., the first one that appears) has an entry but the other table does not.  `OUTER JOIN`s are useful for these situations where you don't necessarily have data entries in all the tables for what you want from a query; they can be confusing at first, but they become very important to using SQL well.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need a couple of `OUTER` joins if I have understood your situation correctly.

```
SELECT ...
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN Registry r ON r.uid = u.id
LEFT JOIN Cities ci ON u.cityid = ci.id
LEFT JOIN Countries co ON u.countryid = co.id
WHERE u.id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, I flipped a coin on who got the correct answer tag :)